# Match with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check a string by `RegExp` with many condition

1. string length must be 7
2. first two digit must be numeric.
3. third digit must be `E`
4. fourth and fifth digit must be numeric and cannot be greater then `12`
5. sixth and seventh digit must be numeric

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
var re = /^[0-9]{2}E(0[0-9]|1[0-2])[0-9]{2}$/;

if (re.test(yourstring))
   // match
else
   // not match
```